# Why does the content of DIV jump down?

Tags: html, css

on the bottom of the first div there is an "anker". It should works like, when you use the anker it should jump to the Markup / next div (Content). But the Problem now, it jumps automatic to the second div, without using the "anker".

```
<div id = 'infoseite_smartphone'>
    <div id = 'programmbox_smartphone'> --> First DIV
       ....
       <div id = 'programmtext'>
           ... --> Content of the first div
       </div>
       <div id = 'nextreferenz'>
         <a href = '#referenzbox_smartphone'>Weiter gehts hier...</a>  --> anker
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id = referenzbox_smartphone'> --> second DIV
       ....
       <div id = 'referenzboxtext'>
           ... --> Content of the second div
       </div>
       <div id = 'nextreferenz'>
         <a href = '#xyz>Weiter gehts hier...</a>  --> anker
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

Not the Media query:

```
#infoseite_smartphone {
    display: none;
}
```

This part works in a media query

```
#infoseite_smartphone {
        display: block;
        height: 71vh;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #programmbox_smartphone {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 66vh;   
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #programmuberschrift {
        width: 97vw;
        font-size: 6vh;
        text-align: right;
    }

    #programmtext {
        width: 97vw;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 4.5vh;
    }

    #referenzbox_smartphone {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 66vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #referenzuberschrift {
        width: 100vw;
        font-size: 6vh;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 2vh;
    }

    #referenztext {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 3.5vh;
        margin-left: 2vw;
    }

    #nextreferenz {
        width: 30vw;
        height: 4vh;
        line-height: 4vh;
        font-size: 2vh;
        background-color: #658F8E;      
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Maybe the css tag Display: block could be the Problem?

wrong

[image]

right:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal:
you are just reloading your page right?
Check if there is an anchor in the url (if there is remove it) and try to go to the top of the page before reloading.

Or, try to load the page using your browser "private mode/incognito mode"

I'm sure the display css property is not the issue here...

Comment: Thx a lot, that was really the Problem, i check the URL and i found the #....., thx

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! You can tag this answer as the solution if this solved your problem ;)